# Calling a javascript method in controller from java - android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am creating a hybrid anrdroid application which uses cordova,ionic and angular.I am trying to implement bar code scanning alone in native java and I am able to call java method from javascript using JavaScriptInterface .But I am unable to pass the return value from java method to javascript . Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: if you are using cordova, you need to use the plugin interface. that is exactly what its for. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using ionic project, you need not implement bar scanner in native java code. Because already many plugins for cordova. 
For bar code scanning, it's better you can make use of `ionic / cordova` barcode scanner plugin which would make your work easier.

> But for your current scenario:

When you scan the image, you will get the image file path. Set that path to a instance variable in java activity class.
From your view, have a setInterval timer and call a javaInterface method which will return the file path.
if the file path getter interface returns a value then clear the java instance variable and the time interval.

Here is a sample code:

```
@JavascriptInterface
        public void scanBarCode() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

 /** Read barcode from ZXing library */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getBarCode() {
            return (barcode!=null ? barcode : "");
        }
```

In your `onActivityResult`, you will be returning the image url.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
```

Now in your JS:

```
var barcodeTimer = setInterval(function () {
    var barcode = Android.getBarCode();
    if (barcode != "") {
        // set it to your $scope
        $scope.$apply();
        clearInterval(barcodeTimer);
    }
}, 2000);
```